# Understand gnu makefile declaration

Tags: gnu-make

What does the following declaration mean. More specifically the ':P' part.
How do I read similar declarations in gnu makefile.

```
BUILD_TOOL         = ${toolname:P}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [BSD make](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)) feature:

> `:P   The path of the node which has the same name as the variable
>       is the value.  If no such node exists or its path is null, then
>       the name of the variable is used.  In order for this modifier to
>       work, the name (node) must at least have appeared on the rhs of
>       a dependency.`

There is nothing similar to that in GNU make; you'll have to set the variable directly and use it in both places (target and variable etc.)